# Using only subset of updatable table fields in INSERT or UPDATE record stored procedure?

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, db2-zos

Consider simple commands:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE table_name (fldX) VALUES (valueX)
UPDATE table_name SET fldX = valueX WHERE table_id = ? AND version_id = ?
```

More often we insert or update only some of the table fields but all examples of CRUD Stored Procedures on INSERT/UPDATE contain all updatable table fields and to use this SPs we need to fill all those parameters.

**Problems with such SPs arise when**:
- user wants to set only subset  (1+) of fields initially so he can't use SP which inserts all fields
- user doesn't always know about all table fields so he can't use SP which updates all fields. I don't want to write the same SP for possible subset of fields.
- user should't have access to SP which updates all fields.
- user/user action doesn't always have permission to change values of all table fields.
- user want to update just 1 field but needs to use all table fields in CALL {table}_update( ... )
In this examples user DOES have access to "PRIMARY KEY" and "VERSION" (timestamp/numeric) columns of record.

---

**Posssible solutions:**

---

- **Solution 0**: Keep using INSERT/UPDATE statements

**Advantages of this approach:**
- it works

**Disadvantages of this approach:**
- security concerns when allowing users direct access to tables
- no way to save user's data when **DELETE**ing record

---

- **Solution 1**: Send part of DML statement as parameter and SP will use it to create Dynamic SQL stament:

```
CALL table_update(p_id AS INT, p_changes CHAR(1000))
-- Parameters: p_changes = "fld1 = 1, fld2 = '01.01.2019', fld3 = 'abc'"
st1 = 'UPDATE table SET' || p_changes || 'WHERE id = p_id';
EXECUTE st1;
```

**Disadvantages of this approach:**
- possible SQL injection
- no caching and optimization available on Dynamic SQL
- can't check input string, etc...

---

- **Solution2**: Send not used values AS **NULL**s and add string parameter with list of columns with values to use actual parameters (even if it's null)

```
PROCEDURE table_update(upd_fields VARCHAR(1000), fld1 CHR(30), fld2 CHAR(30))
-- If we want to update only fld1 we should execute
CALL table_update('fld1', value1, NULL)
```

**Disadvantages of this approach:**
- If SP will change ordering of parameters in the future this system will break
- Statements again will be prepared dynamically so no caching.
- complexity of creating 'ins_fields' or 'upd_fields' parameters

---

- **Solution 3**: Send updates using XML string with all changes.

```
PROCEDURE table_update(record_updates XML)
-- or even
PROCEDURE table_edit(table_changes XML) -- all INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statemens together
```

**Advantages of this approach:**
- can be used for INSERTs/UPDATEs/DELETEs in 1 SP call
- only 1 parameter to list all updated fields.

**Disadvantages of this approach:**
- transfers more data (because XML)
- lower performance because of need to parse XML on server
- increases Stored Procedure complexity.
- increases Client code complexity (to create XML string)

---

**So what solutions am I missing? Which are considered mainstream/best/universal?**

**How does this problem is solved in modern ORMs? DO they use 1st, 2nd or 3rd approach?**

Personally I would like to use 3rd solution (with XML parameter) but I need examples:
1) Examples of schemas for such XML parameters.
2) Examples of Stored Procedures that parse XML parameter

**Currently used environment**: executing direct INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statements using SQL passthrough (ODBC) from Visual FoxPro applcation. DBMS: **DB2 for z/OS v10**.

Comment: ... I think part of the problem is that you're conceptualizing your SP as a raw "update these fields" statement.  But if you're doing validity and authorization checking, it would be better to think of them as specific actions that affect a subset of fields - `RenewMembership(memberId)` instead of `UpdateMemberTable(... list of fields...)`.  This means you end up with more SPs, but they're more easily understandable.  Otherwise, move all this logic into an API and check permissions there, and update with a raw statement.

Comment: Also note: on-delete triggers are a thing.  You should be able to call `PREPARE` in a stored procedure, meaning you could whitelist-validate field names and provide parameters as normal (and the db does somewhat cache prepared statements).  Stringly-typed data has other problems, though.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer; DB2 allows parameter overloading:

```
PROCEDURE update_widgets(p_id INTEGER, p_color VARCHAR(40) )
PROCEDURE update_widgets(p_id INTEGER, p_quantity INTEGER )
PROCEDURE update_widgets(p_id INTEGER, p_price DECIMAL(9,2) )
PROCEDURE update_widgets(p_id INTEGER, p_quantity INTEGER, p_price DECIMAL(9,2) )
PROCEDURE update_widgets(p_id INTEGER, p_color VARCHAR(40) , p_quantity INTEGER, p_price DECIMAL(9,2) )
. . .
```

As long as your arguments are not ambiguous, you can have as many variants as you like

Another solution is to have all possible updateable rows be nullable parameters, and use null as a no-update check:

```
UPDATE widgets SET price = :p_price WHERE id=:p_id AND :p_price IS NOT NULL;
UPDATE widgets SET color = :p_color WHERE id=:p_id AND :p_color IS NOT NULL;
. . .
```